# Application resetting on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, asp.net

We have an ASP.NET application running on IIS 7.5. In the Application_Start, we are building an index file.

We're noticing that after some time of non-use, the application resets, and run its Application_Start process again, resulting in the re-building of the index. I've disabled the application pool from recycling every x minutes, but it didn't solve the issue.

How can we prevent this application reset from happening?

Bdw, I'm new to deploying to IIS and ASP.NET so sry if it's a newbie question.

Thanks!
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 1):

Is it the only application that uses this pool? maybe the pool is reset due to overuse of an other application. Either way the application migth restart for many reasons. ex. by changing the web.cofig file.My point is that maybe your application must be capable to handle the restart because this might occur due to many reasons that you may not predict. So there might be a case that the application will restart and rebuild the index.

Answer (score 1):

In the App Pool Properties, disable the 20 minute default Idle Timeout (as well as the regular recycle, which you say you've done).

ASP.Net will unload an appdomain if the contents of the folder containing it change; as long as the site's stable and deployed, it should be able to run without unloading, unless something bad/funky is going on.